# Default scope of seam component

Tags: java, seam

If we do not declare scope type in seam component, what is the scope type of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no exact answer for this and this is a basic point that you should understand well. 
Read this for more info:[Seam contexts](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/snapshot/en-US/html/concepts.html#d0e3564)

Summary:

1. If your component is a **SFSB**(Stateful Session Bean) the default scope will be "**Conversation**" sope. However if you didn't propagate it taking proper actions this default conversion normally exists only within the request cycle. So you may see this as event scoped.(*You should read more*)
2. If the component is a **SLSB** the default scope will be "**Stateless**".
3. If your component is a **POJO** the default scope will be "**event**".